# Conver .htaccess to nginx config

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I have a some .htaccess. I'm try conver by https://winginx.com/en/htaccess but it not work. Help me convert it.

```
# .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
#moz.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} rogerbot [OR]
#majestic.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot [OR]
#moz.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} dotbot [OR]
#gigablast.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} gigabot [OR]
#ahrefs.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AhrefsBot
#Semrush.con
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Semrush.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* – [F]
Deny from .ahrefs.com
Deny from .dotnetdotcom.org
Deny from .amazonaws.com
Deny from .semrush.com
Deny from .moz.com
```

AND

```
#block bots
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BLEXBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlackWidow.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Nutch.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Jetbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebVac.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Stanford.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*scooter.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*naver.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*dumbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Hatena Antenna.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*grub.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*looksmart.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebZip.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*larbin.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*b2w/0.1.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Copernic.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*psbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Python-urllib.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NetMechanic.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*URL_Spider_Pro.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*CherryPicker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EmailCollector.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EmailSiphon.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebBandit.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EmailWolf.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Email.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ExtractorPro.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*CopyRightCheck.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Crescent.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SiteSnagger.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ProWebWalker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*CheeseBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LNSpiderguy.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ia_archiver.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Alexibot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Teleport.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MIIxpc.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Telesoft.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Website Quester.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*moget.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebStripper.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebSauger.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebCopier.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NetAnts.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Mister PiX.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebAuto.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*TheNomad.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WWW-Collector-E.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*RMA.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*libWeb/clsHTTP.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*asterias.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*httplib.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*turingos.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*spanner.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Harvest.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*InfoNaviRobot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Bullseye.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebBandit.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NICErsPRO.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Microsoft URL Control.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*DittoSpyder.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Foobot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebmasterWorldForumBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SpankBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BotALot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*lwp-trivial.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebmasterWorld.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BunnySlippers.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*URLy Warning.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Wget.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LinkWalker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*cosmos.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*hloader.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*humanlinks.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LinkextractorPro.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Offline Explorer.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Mata Hari.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LexiBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Web Image Collector.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*The Intraformant.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*True_Robot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlowFish.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SearchEngineWorld.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*JennyBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MIIxpc.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BuiltBotTough.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ProPowerBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BackDoorBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*toCrawl/UrlDispatcher.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebEnhancer.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*suzuran.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebViewer.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*VCI.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Szukacz.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*QueryN.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Openfind.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Openbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Webster.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EroCrawler.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LinkScan.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Keyword.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Kenjin.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Iron33.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Bookmark search tool.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*GetRight.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*FairAd Client.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Gaisbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Aqua_Products.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Radiation Retriever 1.1.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Flaming AttackBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Oracle Ultra Search.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MSIECrawler.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*PerMan.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*searchpreview.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*sootle.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Enterprise_Search.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Bot mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ChinaClaw.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Custo.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*DISCo.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Download Demon.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*eCatch.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EirGrabber.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EmailSiphon.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EmailWolf.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Express WebPictures.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ExtractorPro.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*EyeNetIE.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*FlashGet.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*GetRight.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*GetWeb!.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Go!Zilla.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Go-Ahead-Got-It.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*GrabNet.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Grafula.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*HMView.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*HTTrack.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Image Stripper.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Image Sucker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Indy Library.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*InterGET.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Internet Ninja.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*JetCar.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*JOC Web Spider.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*larbin.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*LeechFTP.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Mass Downloader.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MIDown tool.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Mister PiX.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Navroad.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NearSite.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NetAnts.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NetSpider.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Net Vampire.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*NetZIP.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Octopus.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Offline Explorer.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Offline Navigator.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*PageGrabber.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Papa Foto.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*pavuk.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*pcBrowser.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*RealDownload.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*ReGet.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SiteSnagger.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SmartDownload.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SuperBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*SuperHTTP.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Surfbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*tAkeOut.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Teleport Pro.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*VoidEYE.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Web Image Collector.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Web Sucker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebAuto.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebCopier.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebFetch.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebGo IS.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebLeacher.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebReaper.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebSauger.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Website eXtractor.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Website Quester.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebStripper.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebWhacker.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WebZIP.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Wget.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Widow.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*WWWOFFLE.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Xaldon WebSpider.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Zeus.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Semrush.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BecomeBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*AhrefsBot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*MJ12bot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*rogerbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*exabot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*Xenu.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*dotbot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*gigabot.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*BlekkoBot.*$ [NC]
```

Comment: Might have better luck over at the SuperUser stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map of each bad agent

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/badagents.conf**

```
map $http_user_agent $badagent {
        default         0;
        ~*BLEXBot     1;
        ~*BlackWidow      1;
}
```

Then in your nginx config include this file

```
http {
   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/badagents.conf;

   server {
        if ($badagent) {
           return 200 "HTTP 200 OK";
        }
   }
}
```

I return 200 on bad agent so that it just thinks it worked and doesn't return anything

**Test Results**

```
$ curl -H "User-Agent: Test blackWiDOW Test" localhost
HTTP 200 OK

$ curl -H "User-Agent: Test BLEXBot Test" localhost
HTTP 200 OK

$ curl -H "User-Agent: Good Agent" localhost
Request is /ROOT/index.html
```